# Configure Memcached Backend via ini file or xml file in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

Trying to configure Zend_Cache_Backend_Memcached via a config.ini or config.xml file. I'm not sure how to represent the array of servers in an ini file as described in the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.cache.backends.html#zend.cache.backends.memcached)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to represent an array while using `Zend_Config_Ini` is to just make some nonsense keys:

```
 cache.backend.memcache.servers.foo.host = host1.example.com
 cache.backend.memcache.servers.foo.port = 11211
 ...
 cache.backend.memcache.servers.bar.host = host2.example.com
 cache.backend.memcache.servers.bar.port = 12345;
```

Comment: useful names might help more than nonsense keys, like some hint to which server it is, but this is pretty much on the money

Comment: Yes, I completely agree that for a self-explanatory config file, useful names are must; however, the key names have no tangible impact on `Zend_Cache`

Answer (score -1):

You can probably put this information in the [Zend_Registry](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.registry.html). If that isn't loaded early enough in the processes, then you can put a big `array` declaration in a php file, and `require_once` it where needed.

Comment: I want to keep all my configs in one place. Specifically in a ini or xml file.

Comment: You can keep your configuration in a single place with either approach. With larger projects though, it's advisable to keep the scope of your config files narrow because some code may not need all settings.

Comment: There is no need to put this information in the registry, you should use the app config for such things, (you can use a php array instead of ini format and get advantages like APC caching see http://dasprids.de) bit putting this in the app config makes sense. I would suggest creating a custom resource plugin, which can then register your cache object in the registry, or use your own singleton implementation to fetch multiple front/backends throught your app.

Comment: This isn't much different than my second suggestion. If you feel the question is lacking in detail, feel free to expand on it in an answer of your own.